# Java join 2 not contains in one expression

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to join two not contains statements into one expression, is it possible? The string must contain either the 'j' or 'i' characters in it

```
String input = "this";
if(!((input.contains("J"))|| (input.contains("i"))) {
System.out.prinltn("your input must contain either a 'J' or an 'i'");

}else{
System.out.prinltn("your input does contain a 'J' or an 'i'");
}
```

input = this

output = your input does not contain a 'J' or an 'i'

expected = your input does contain a 'J' or an 'i'

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use regexps, it is just one expression and you can change it in one place later if your rules changed (instead of growing if/else clauses)

```
String input = "this";
System.out.println(input.matches(".*[ij].*"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is ok, it's just missing some parentheses:

```
    String input = "this";
    if (!((input.contains("J")) || (input.contains("i")))) {
        System.out.println("your input does not contain a 'J' or an 'i'");
    } else {
        System.out.println("your input does contain a 'J' or an 'i'");
    }
```

Fast way to check: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

OR, you can reverse the if and make the code more readable:

```
    String input = "this";
    if (input.contains("J") || input.contains("i")) {
        System.out.println("your input does contain a 'J' or an 'i'");
    } else {
        System.out.println("your input does not contain a 'J' or an 'i'");
    }
```

Comment: thanks timeFly, the missing parenthesis was the problem alright. thank you

Answer (score 1):

just remove the ! and it should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

'!' symbol in if condition returns false if string contains 'J' or 'i'. That's why you not getting expected output.So, remove '!' from if. Try below code.

```
String input = "this";
if(((input.contains("J"))|| (input.contains("i"))) {
System.out.prinltn("your input does not contain a 'J' or an 'i'");

else{
System.out.prinltn("your input does contain a 'J' or an 'i'");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar, but your suggestion checks for the positive condition, I need to check for the negative condition i.e. if "the sting does not contain a 'j' or the string does not contain an 'i'